# Capistrano 3 Start Server Error (Rails 4.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, capistrano3

This is my spec for deployment to my staging:

- Rails 4.2.5
- Capistrano 3.4.1
- Thin 1.7.0
- Nginx 1.4.6

Everything works fine, capistrano also able to deploy and run the server

**BUT**

When I try to access the staging, it's always internal server error and written on `log/thin.log` on the rails app:

```
Unexpected error while processing request: Missing 'secret_token' and 
'secret_key_base' for 'production' environment, set these values in 
'config/secrets.yml'
```

I also have set the `secret_key_base` for production environment generated from `rake secret RAILS_ENV=production`

if I kill the running server process run by capistrano and manually run the server using `bundle exec thin -p [MY_PORT] -e production -d start`, the error disappears and everything is normal

So,

- it passes nginx so the error must be in thin or capistrano
- it bugs me everytime I deploy to production then I must kill the
  server process and start it manually

my questions are:

1. why thin server started by capistrano always have error with missing
   `secret_key_base` and `secret_token` although I already have it on
   my `secrets.yml`?
2. how to fix it? I'm out of options

Comment: is your `secrets.yml` file in version control ?

Comment: no, added it to gitignore, I use `set :linked_files %w{config/secrets.yml}`